# MS Excel 2007 : How do I increase number in a cell after every printout

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I am printing an Excel document say 100 copies.

I have a field like "Copy No : "0001""

I need to increment this number after every printout so that every print has a Copy No: 0002, Copy No: 0003.....Copy No..0100

I mean to say when I give the print job and set it to 100 copies, the said number should increment and print automatically.

Is this possible using a Macro or some formulae ?? :)

Comment: How will you be printing? Just `File` > `Print` and one at a time? Or all 1000 at once via a macro, say, then reset to 1 for next time it's run?

Comment: ... Just as an idea... http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Excel/usetheBeforePrinteventtoaddinformationtoaheaderorfooterbeforethesheetisprinted.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to John Bustos original code, added some more and it works

```
Sub PrintIncrement()

   Let x = 0
   Do While x < 100
   ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=100, Collate:=True
   Dim num As Integer
   Range("L10").Select
   num = Range("L10").Value
   num = num + 1
   Range("L10").Value = num
   x = x + 1
   Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following macro:

```
Sub PrintIncrement()   

   ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True   
   Dim num As Integer   
   Range("A1").Select   
   num = Range("A1").Value   
   num = num + 1   
   Range("A1").Value = num   

End Sub
```

tell me if you have problems

Comment: Just as a quicker way to do this, you could condense the incrementing code to one line as `Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value + 1`

Comment: @ John Bustos @ AHC

Your macro prints just 1 page with cell value A1=1, increments the cell A1 to 2, then stops. Does not work! :/
I tried changing Copies:=10, but still will print 1 print only..